# Terminal is not updating after code is written in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Live Share in VS Code but everytime we write a code, it seems that the terminal is not updated and does not output the code that is written. How do I fix this?

I think the issue that I've saved it to a file? Does anyone know if I have to manually save it each time or something? Thanks.

Comment: what does the terminal need to be updated for? what are you doing with your file in the terminal?

Comment: Isn't it only after running the file that the content is displayed in the terminal? Are you trying to express the log?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code must be saved to execute the updated code from the terminal.
To enable auto-save follow:-

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or
   <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on macOS.
2. Type **user settings** and select **Preferences: Open User Settings**.
3. Type auto save and set the **Files: Auto Save setting**.
4. You can search for auto save delay and set the value. The code is saved every 1,000 milliseconds (1 second) by default.

*Check sites like [source](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/vscode-toggle-auto-save) for details*